# multiple selections in form using perl mechanize

Tags: forms, perl, firefox, mechanize

I am having some doubts in handling forms using perl.

I am using perl mechanize Firefox module. The code i use to process form .

```
$mech->form_name("CFForm_1");
my $form = $mech -> current_form;
$mech->select( 'state', '$state' );
$mech->select( 'country', '$country' ); # Selection box for state
$mech->click_button(value=>"Search");  #Selection box for country
```

For a form like this i use 2 while loops to get select every state and country.

[image]

I would like to know if there is any alternate way. for select the options (state and country)
one by one. Need some suggestion.

Thanks in advance.